# parsing the list of transforms of the SVG transform attribute

Tags: c++, c, parsing, c++11, svg

The SVG 1.1 specification states:

> The value of the ‘transform’ attribute is a transform-list, which is
>   defined as a list of transform definitions, which are applied in the
>   order provided. The individual transform definitions are separated by
>   whitespace and/or a comma.

It also gives an example:

```
<g transform="translate(-10,-20) scale(2) rotate(45) translate(5,10)">
  <!-- graphics elements go here -->
</g>
```

I use a separate XML parser to obtain transform-list attributes. Is it possible to do the parsing job with the facilities the standard library provides, without implementing a parsing algorithm?

Comment: give us the bigger picture; what is the actual *problem* you're trying to solve? you may not have to parse it at all

Comment: recognizing and extracting the parameters in a transform-list

Comment: i get it, but what i'm really asking is *for what purpose*?

Comment: btw, are you familiar with [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)?

Comment: I'd like to implement a subset of SVG.

Comment: a subset of SVG - as an XML parsing engine, or a JavaScript API?

Comment: @EliranMalka I use pugixml for XML parsing, but I need to still parse the contents of individual attributes.

Comment: it seems that SAX has got what you're after - see the [`Attributes` API](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html). voting to close this as the question seems to be about a recommendation for a library.

Comment: @EliranMalka You misunderstood my question completely, I've got the XML parsing part covered.

Comment: ok, i get it now (after the edit). withdrawing my vote.

Answer (score 2):

Not with standard library.

But SVG++ library 1.0 was released (https://github.com/svgpp/svgpp). And you can use it like this:

```
#include <svgpp/svgpp.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace svgpp;

struct Context
{
  void transform_matrix(const boost::array<double, 6> & matrix)
  {
    std::copy(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), 
      std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  Context context;
  value_parser<tag::type::transform_list>::parse(tag::attribute::transform(), context,
    std::string("translate(-10,-20) scale(2) rotate(45) translate(5,10)"), tag::source::attribute());
  return 0;
}
```

Boost is required, but no additional building or linking - library is header-only.

Answer (score 1):

The XML parsing library will (most likely) only provide you with a string value associated with an attribute in the parsed tree.

You will need to implement parsing yourself for the attribute value(s), or find an svg parsing library that does this.

Comment: True, true, but I am looking for ways to avoid this. Parsing, the hard wall of ignorance we programmers often encounter.